# How to resize the "Title" Column in the "Posts" section in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

The width of Title is too short and the display is bad.

[image: Title width too short]

Comment: If you look at the top right corner, you should see a button called "Screen Options". Click off some of the columns, you should have more space to read the Titles of your posts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the top right corner, you should see a button called "Screen Options". Click off some of the columns, you should have more space to read the Titles of your posts.

Answer (score 1):

To make the min-width work you would need the auto algorithm

I put on an custom-admin.css stylesheet (loaded only on backend)

```
table.table-view-list.posts{
 table-layout:auto
}

td.column-title,
th.column-title{
 min-width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used [Admin CSS MU](https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-css-mu/) plugin which lets to add custom CSS to the admin theme. Then I added the following CSS code and it works like a charm.

```
.table-view-list .column-primary {
    width: 12em;
}
```

If you wish, you can customize the width for each page separately by adding the page's class name after the `table-view-list` class:

```
.table-view-list.post .column-primary {
    width: 12em;
}
```

Hope it helps :-)